# Unable see any WhatsApp media folder in Lumia 630

Tags: 8.1, whatsapp

I"m able to see all WhatsApp photos and videos when I open gallery ('Photos' is the gallery name in 8.1). But I checked everywhere and couldn't find where those media files are located. I searched in WhatsApp folder and could see only folder named 'backup' there. I actually wanted to move some of the WhatsApp photos and videos from phone to computer.

Phone : Lumia 630
Os : Windows Phone 8.1

Addition : I just noticed, not just WhatsApp even the photos and videos are unavailable.

Comment: Sorry.. I'm able to find all under below path.Computer\Windows Phone\SD card\Pictures

Answer (score 2):

It is really simple... You need not go to whatsapp folder. Instead connect your phone to the computer and follow this path...... My computer\Windows phone\SD card\Pictures\ whatsapp (or) My computer\Windows phone\Phone\Pictures\ whatsapp

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp saves all its media under the Pictures folder.

On your phone, use the Microsoft [**Files**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/Files/9WZDNCRFJ3PL) app to navigate to **`SD card > Pictures > Whatsapp`**, and you will find all the media that came through WhatsApp, including audio, documents and videos. Sometimes audio is in a folder named PTT.

If you cannot find any media in the folder specified, or the folder itself under pictures, that means your default save location is your device's storage. Check **`Phone > Pictures > Whatsapp`**